# how to move the whole main-video-wrap div into video-list-Wrapping div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

*Thanks @Kathara Your help is greatly appreciated*

**I have created the video layout with a picture in picture mode option click the video move to the background works fine, but I need to move the whole video wrap into the main video wrap not only the video, with the card image name, and dropdowns also moved on within the video list and also changing the id attribute of videoWraping element how to modify it?**

**here is my demo code**

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
 
<div  class="container-fluid m-0" id="videos m-0">

      <div class="row vh-100 align-items-end align-items-lg-center m-0" >
  <div class="col-12 offset-lg-8 col-lg-4 text-center text-lg-end ">
        <div  id="VisualMedia">

      <div  class=" main-video mainVideoWrap" id="cardvideo_localstream">
         <video id="video-main" class="video1" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/ve0apo59semvv70/example-video-1.mp4?raw=1 " muted autoplay loop type="video/mp4" ></video>
        <div class="card-img-overlay p-0  " id="mainCard">
          <div>
            <span class="text-capitalize user-name">
              <i class="icon-user pe-1"></i>videoBg
            </span>
            <div id="dropDown" class="dropdown float-end">
              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger me-3 mt-2 dropdown-toggle" type="button"  id="userMenu"   data-bs-toggle="dropdown"   aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="icon-dot"></i>
              </button>
              <ul id="drop"  class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end"   aria-labelledby="userMenu"  >
                <li>
                  <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#"  >
                    <i class="bi bi-mic-mute m-1"></i>Start Audio</a >
                  </li>
                <li>
                  <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#"  ><i class="bi bi-camera-video-off m-1"></i>Stop Video</a >
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#" ><i class="bi bi-person-x m-1"></i>Remove</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="mainlogo">
            <img src="./client_img.png"  alt="logo"  class="img-fluid rounded float-end" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   
      <!-- <div class="row vh-100 align-items-end align-items-lg-center m-0"> -->
        <div class=" video-list listofvideos">
          <div class="position-relative videoWrap" id="cardvideo_remotestream">
            <video  src=" https://www.dropbox.com/s/se8r4svvnt2qpfu/example-video-2.mp4?raw=1 " muted  autoplay loop type="video/mp4" ></video>
            <div class="card-img-overlay p-0  " id="imgCard">
              <div>
                <span class="text-capitalize user-name">
                  <i class="icon-user pe-1"></i>videolist1
                </span>
                <div id="dropDown" class="dropdown float-end">
                  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger me-3 mt-2 dropdown-toggle"  type="button"  id="userMenu"  data-bs-toggle="dropdown"   aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="icon-dot"></i>
                  </button>
                  <ul id="drop" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="userMenu" >
                    <li>
                      <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#"  ><i class="bi bi-mic-mute m-1"></i>Start Audio</a  >
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#"   ><i class="bi bi-camera-video-off m-1"></i>Stop Video</a >
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#"  ><i class="bi bi-person-x m-1"></i>Remove</a  >
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
          
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="position-relative videoWrap" id="cardvideo_remotestream">
            <video   src=" https://www.dropbox.com/s/se8r4svvnt2qpfu/example-video-2.mp4?raw=1 "  muted  ></video>
            <div class="card-img-overlay p-0  " id="imgCard">
              <div>
                <span class="text-capitalize user-name">
                  <i class="icon-user pe-1"></i>videolist2
                </span>
                <div id="dropDown" class="dropdown float-end">
                  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger me-3 mt-2 dropdown-toggle"  type="button"   id="userMenu"  data-bs-toggle="dropdown"   aria-expanded="false" >
                    <i class="icon-dot"></i>
                  </button>
                  <ul  id="drop"   class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="userMenu" >
                    <li>
                 <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#"  ><i class="bi bi-mic-mute m-1"></i>Start Audio</a  >
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#"  ><i class="bi bi-camera-video-off m-1"></i>Stop Video</a >
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#"   ><i class="bi bi-person-x m-1"></i>Remove</a >
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
           
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="position-relative videoWrap" id="cardvideo_remotestream">
            <video  src=" https://www.dropbox.com/s/se8r4svvnt2qpfu/example-video-2.mp4?raw=1 "  muted  autoplay loop type="video/mp4"></video>
            <div class="card-img-overlay p-0  " id="imgCard">
              <div>
                <span class="text-capitalize user-name">
                  <i class="icon-user pe-1"></i>videolist3
                </span>
                <div id="dropDown" class="dropdown float-end">
                  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger me-3 mt-2 dropdown-toggle" type="button"  id="userMenu" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" >
                    <i class="icon-dot"></i>
                  </button>
                  <ul id="drop" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="userMenu">
                    <li>
                      <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#" ><i class="bi bi-mic-mute m-1"></i>Start Audio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="bi bi-camera-video-off m-1"></i>Stop Video</a >
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#" ><i class="bi bi-person-x m-1"></i>Remove</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
           
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="position-relative videoWrap" id="cardvideo_remotestream">
            <video  src=" https://www.dropbox.com/s/se8r4svvnt2qpfu/example-video-2.mp4?raw=1 " muted  autoplay loop type="video/mp4"></video>
            <div class="card-img-overlay p-0 " id="imgCard">
              <div>
                <span class="text-capitalize user-name">
                  <i class="icon-user pe-1"></i>videolist4
                </span>
                <div id="dropDown" class="dropdown float-end">
                  <button  class="btn btn-sm btn-danger me-3 mt-2 dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="userMenu" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"
                  >
                    <i class="icon-dot"></i>
                  </button>
                  <ul  id="drop"  class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end"  aria-labelledby="userMenu" >
                    <li>
                      <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#" ><i class="bi bi-mic-mute m-1"></i>Start Audio</a >
                    </li>
                    <li>  <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#"
                        ><i class="bi bi-camera-video-off m-1"></i>Stop Video</a  >
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#"
                        ><i class="bi bi-person-x m-1"></i>Remove</a  >
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
        
            </div>
          </div>
        <!-- </div> -->
      </div>

      <!-- row column -->
    </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  <script src="./bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


</html>
```

*style.css*

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  /* main video */
  .main-video video{
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  
  .main-video #mainlogo{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 2rem;
    right: 1rem;
  }
  .main-video #mainlogo img{
    width: 40px;
  }
  
  #main-video{
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  
  .videoWrap{
    position: relative;
  max-width: 320px;
  display: inline-block;
  }
  .videoWrap #logo{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2rem;
  right: 1rem;
  }
  .videoWrap #logo img{
  width: 40px;
  }
  
  .video-list video{
  
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  max-width: 320px;
  margin: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
  border-radius: 1.25rem;
  z-index: 2;
  }
  .user-name{
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  padding: 0.125rem 0.25rem;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0.5rem 0 0 1rem;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width:768px){
  .videoWrap,
  .video-list video{
      max-width: 217px;
  }
  }
  
  
  @media only screen and (min-device-width: 200px) and (max-device-width: 992px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    .videoWrap,
    .video-list video{
        max-width: 150px;
    }
   .videoWrap, #dropDown {
      margin: -0.8rem 0.2rem -1.8rem -0.3rem;
      left: 31px;
      bottom: 4px;
    }
    .videoWrap .user-name{
      margin: -0.8rem 0.2rem -1.8rem -0.3rem;
      left: 31px;
      bottom: 4px;
    }
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width:480px){
  .videoWrap,
  .video-list video{
      max-width: 149px;
      bottom: 4rem;
  }
  .videoWrap #logo{
    bottom: 1.5rem;
  }
  .videoWrap #logo img{
    width: 30px;
  }
  }
```

*jsfile*

```
// using jQuery
var initVideoSwapping = function() {
    // check if there is an element first
    if ($('.video-list #imgCard').length > 0 && $('#video-main').length > 0) {
        $('.video-list .videoWrap').on('click', function() {
            var $thisVideoWrapId =  $(this).find('.videoWrap');
            var $mainVideoWrapId= $('.main-video')
        
              $mainVideoWrapId.attr('id', 'cardvideo_remotestream')
                 $thisVideoWrapId.attr('id', 'cardvideo_localstream')
            

// video change

            var $thisVideo = $(this).find('video');
            var $mainVideo = $('#video-main');
            
            // clone the two elements to change them
            // without modifying the original element
            var $thisVideoClone = $thisVideo.clone();
            var $mainVideoClone = $mainVideo.clone();
            
            // exchange the ids
            $thisVideoClone.attr('id', 'video-main');
            $mainVideoClone.attr('id', '');
            
            // insert the clones before the originals
            // and remove the originals
            $thisVideoClone.insertBefore($mainVideo);
    
            $mainVideo.remove();
            
            $mainVideoClone.insertBefore($thisVideo);
            
            $thisVideo.remove();
        });
    }
}


$(function() {
    initVideoSwapping();
});
```

**main-videoWrap <--> video-list videoWrap, video-list videoWrap<--> main-videoWrap
How to append to move and add the video element with a single click using JavaScript or jQuery?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked into the code you have provided and found a few bugs.

Replace: 
`$('#main-video').length` with `$('.main-video').length`  
`var $mainVideo = $('#video-main');` with `$mainVideo = $('#video-main');`

In also restructured your code so that the clicked video is used as main and removed from the DOM. Please use it and test let me know if works as you would want. If not, just comment on this answer and I will see if I can make some improvements.

```js
// using jQuery
var initVideoSwapping = function () {

    // check if there is an element first
    if ($('.video-list .videoWrap').length > 0 && $('.main-video').length > 0) {
        
        $('.video-list .videoWrap').on('click', function () {

            var $thisVideoWrapId =  $(this).find('.videoWrap');
            var $mainVideoWrapId= $('.main-video');

            if ($mainVideoWrapId.attr('id') !== 'cardvideo_remotestream') {
                $mainVideoWrapId.attr('id', 'cardvideo_remotestream');
            } else {
                $mainVideoWrapId.attr('id', 'cardvideo_localstream');
            }

            if ($thisVideoWrapId.attr('id') !== 'cardvideo_localstream') {
                $thisVideoWrapId.attr('id', 'cardvideo_localstream');
            } else {
                $thisVideoWrapId.attr('id', 'cardvideo_remotestream');
            }
            
            var $thisVideo = $(this).find('video');
            var $thisVideoSrc = $thisVideo.attr('src');
            var $mainVideo = $('#video-main');
            var $mainVideoSrc = $mainVideo.attr('src');;
            
            // Replace main video source with clicked video source
            $mainVideo.attr('src', $thisVideoSrc);
            
            // Replace clicked video with main video source
            $thisVideo.attr('src', $mainVideoSrc);

        });
    }
}

$(function () {
    initVideoSwapping();
});
```

Comment: thanks for supporting! i've try this code.when I click the video they're all removed.

Comment: My bad. I thought you wanted them removed. I see that you only wanted the clones removed. I will adjust the code and use element cloning and see if it works as you want.

Comment: I have updated the answer. By the way, you don't need cloning of the elements. Just changing the video source is ok.

Comment: Thanks for your support! your help is greatly appreciated. That's works fine, video's changing works normally, but .main-video id value change in single click ,but when i click again i need  the video-list, the  .main-video and video-wrap  id changes  simultaneously, i.e. local stream<--> remote stream, remote stream into local stream.  have been trying to find the solution, but I couldn't. I am struggling from past one week to find the solution

Comment: Maybe I have not understood clearly how the id  need to change. I have updated the answer to alternate the id attributes.