# how to exchange the attribute values simultaneously on single click event using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I want to replace #cardvieo_localstream with #cardvideo_remotestream at the first click, again I click the same element, I want to change #cardvideo_remotestream back #cardvieo_localstream, I'm not sharp at jQuery yet, but I'm trying to learn. I appreciate all help I can get.**

*I've try this code but working on first click. but not working on second click*

```
$('.video-list .videoWrap').on('click', function() {
 

    var $thisVideoWrap = $(this).find('.video-list .videoWrap');
            
            var $mainVideoWrap = $('.mainVideoWrap');
    
                 if ($(this).attr('id') === '#cardvideo_localStream') {
                    $(this).attr('id', '#cardvideo_remotestream');
                 }
                 else if($(this).attr('id') == '#cardvideo_localStream') {
                    $(this).attr('id', '#cardvideo_local');
                    $mainVideoWrap.attr('id', 'cardvideo_remotestream');
                 }

});
```

Comment: console `$(this).attr('id')`, Id will be `cardvideo_localStream` not `#cardvideo_localStream`

Comment: Hello R Sukumar. Can you explain a bit more about what you are trying to accomplish? and also, can you post HTML. Is this a toggle switch(on and off) or are the "Cardvideo" cards showing different content on click?

Comment: @somdow I want replace the attribute value's using single click event again and again,

Comment: Your JavaScript code is wrong, please provide the HTML code so that it will be easier to understand.

Comment: @Rodgath here is my html code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73510177/how-to-move-the-whole-main-video-wrap-div-into-video-list-wrapping-div

Comment: @somdow here my sample html code

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73510177/how-to-move-the-whole-main-video-wrap-div-into-video-list-wrapping-div/73516346#73516346

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change An Id Attribute because of id is a unique value  Only use the Classname, I swap the elements successfully

```
// using jQuery
var initVideoSwapping = function () {
    // check if there is an element first
    if ($('.video-list .videoWrap').length > 0) {
        $('.video-list .videoWrap').on('click', function () {
            var $thisVideo = $(this).find('video')[0];
            var $mainVideo = $('.mainVideoWrap').find('video')[0];
            swapNodes($thisVideo, $mainVideo)
        });
    }
}
function swapNodes(a, b) {
    var aparent = a.parentNode;
    var asibling = a.nextSibling === b ? a : a.nextSibling;
    b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b);
    aparent.insertBefore(b, asibling);
}

$(function () {
    initVideoSwapping();
});
```